# PHP cant get "img src" value

Tags: php, html

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form action="./test2.php" method="POST">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA" name="Image_left" data-filename="Image_left">
            <input type="submit" value="Enter"/>
        </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($method == "POST")
{
    $image_left = $_post['Image_left'];
    $test="";
}
else
    {
    //GET
}
?>
```

Hi guyz,
I am new to PHP and was wondering that how to get the img "src" value given the above html webpage content.

I thought puting "$_POST[*tag name*]" would obtain the value and store in the variable but while debugging  i received this error,

> Notice: Undefined variable: _post in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\captchahtml\test2.php on line 6

How do i go about obtaining the src value of a "img" tag with a specific name? (assumption there are a number of img tags with different names)

Comment: as ur notice use $_POST intead of $_post

Comment: You can use a field input with type hidden with the same value that the src of the img tag

Answer (score 3):

simple answer is.. you cant get the value of anything to do with an image tag.  Its not data thats passed through the form.

You would need to somehow put the value of the image name in a hidden input field. Something like this.

```
<img src="<?php echo 'someServerGeneratedFilename.jpg' ?>"/> // or you could use javascript to populate this and the input value.
<input type="hidden" name="imageValue" value="<?php echo 'someServerGeneratedFilename.jpg' ?>"/>
```

then on your server you should be able to access the post vars onSubmit:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['imageValue'];
```

Answer (score 2):

`<img>` tags are not part of form elements which can be submitted to another page ordinarily. You'll have to use some tricks for that

Comment: e.g. use javascript to set the value in a hidden form element.